# Outlook 2003 constantly prompting for user name and password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

We have an Exchange server at our organization. One of our users is having an odd problem. First of all, she shares her computer with one other person. The two of them use only one Windows user account, but they have separate Outlook profiles. One of the Outlook profiles works just fine. The other one, though, is the one with the odd problem. The user seems to be able to send and receive e-mail just fine. The problem is that Outlook is constantly prompting her for her user name and password. She's definitely typing them correctly and checking the "Remember my password" checkbox doesn't help.

In an effort to fix this problem, I recreated her Outlook profile, but that didn't help. Using the "Detect and Repair" feature didn't help either. I verified that the user's Outlook settings were correct. I uninstalled and re-installed Microsoft Office, but that didn't help. I ended up wiping the drive entirely and re-imaging the computer. I set the two users up with the same configuration (one Windows user account, two Outlook profiles). That was the only thing that fixed it. Once I verified that everything was working again, I returned the computer to the user. Within two days, the user reported that the same problem had returned. I went and verified that the problem had, in fact, returned. What in the world could be causing this? For now, the user is using Outlook Web Access, which appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use PKI at your work?  When outlook does that at my employer, we need to connect to the PKI server, and manually install the certificate for that person.

Also, If they are sharing a login, then its going to pass the currently logged in user to the exchange server. If that currently logged in user does not have rights to that mailbox, you will be prompted.  Perhaps you should give the logged in user full access to both mailboxes.. (although this means they could send email as each other, depends on your security policies)

Comment: We do not use PKI. Also, the normal behavior for using Outlook with credentials other than the ones your Windows user account has is that it prompts you a single time. As long as you enter the correct credentials, the prompt should go away. This is not the case with this user. I'm probably going to upgrade them to Office 2007, which should hopefully get rid of this problem. Thanks very much for your insight and your time!